# How to take screenshot using getUserMedia(); API in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, screenshot

So, I have to take screenshot of screen and draw it on a canvas, I have read that it can be done using js `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()` API but cant find its correct uses.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

There is a complete walk through of your use case here:

https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/